# Prove that $AB=BA=0$ for two idempotent matrices.

Tags: matrices

Suppose that $A, B$ are idempotent matrices ($A^2=A$), such that $A + B$ is idempotent, prove that $AB = BA = 0$

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to prove $AB+BA=0$ ?

Comment: No it is definitely AB=BA=0

Comment: Probably there is a typo on your book/list/etc...

Comment: @Belgi Thanks..

Comment: @GitGud - No problem, I was doing the same thing and I thought it would work

Comment: It must be a typo in the question.

Comment: With square matrices over a characteristic $0$ field K, the following generalization ($n\geq 2$) is actually true. Assume $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ are idempotents. If $p_1+\ldots+p_n$ is idempotent, then $p_ip_j=0$ for all $i\neq j$. Note that the converse is trivial, so this is actually an equivalence.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is true in every ring where you can divide by $2$.
So it is true in particular for matrices.

We have $(A+B)^2=A^2+AB+BA+B^2=A+AB+BA+B$.
Since $A+B$ is idempotent, it follows that 
$$AB+BA=0.$$
We call this equation (E).

Right-multiply (E) by $B$. 
We find $AB+BAB=0$, hence $AB=-BAB$.

Left-multiply (E) by $B$.
This yields $BAB+BA=0$, hence $BA=-BAB$.

Equating the last two equations, we find $AB=BA$.

Now $AB+BA=0$ clearly yields $2AB=2BA=0$.
Dividing by $2$, we get
$$
AB=BA=0.
$$

Comment: Very nice! I thought in this direction when I saw I coldn't get the result, but I figured it was a typo and I tried to find a trivial example so I tooked $B=A$ and then I saw that in $F_2$ I get such an example. Did you know this before, or just proved it ? (+1)

Comment: Could you give me such example? I'm not able of find one

Answer (score 9):

This is incorrect.

For example take $F=\mathbb{F}_{2}$ the field with two elements and
$A=B=I$ over $F$.

$A,B$ are clearly idempotent and $$A+B=I+I=2I=0$$ hence $$(A+B)^{2}=0^{2}=0=A+B$$
is also idempotent.

But $$AB=BA=I^{2}=I\neq0$$

From your assumption you can only get $AB+BA=0$.

Comment: Yes I can only seem to get $AB+BA=0$ from this assumption. Could possibly be a typo.

Comment: @Chance: It is true for square matrices over a field in characteristic distinct from $2$. See my answer.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain ? maybe I can improve my answer.

Comment: If you combine your answer with Julien's, you can arrive at $AB=BA=0$

Comment: @Chance - Not in general, You have to assume $1+1\neq 0$