# If a skew-symmetric real matrix has all eigenvalues zero, must it be the zero matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, skew-symmetric-matrices

This can be easily verified for $2\times2$ and $3\times3$ matrices, but can the result be generalised?

Comment: The answer is yes. One way to see this is to consider the trace of $A^2$ where $A$ is the skew-symmetric matrix in question.

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix has real entries: Any matrix with all eigenvalues zero is nilpotent, the only nilpotent skew-symmetric matrix is the zero matrix.

Comment: Begs the question, why the only nilpotent skew-symmetric matrix is the zero matrix.

Comment: $A^2$ is symmetric

Comment: So now the question is why the only nilpotent symmetric matrix is the zero matrix. But of course symmetric matrices are diagonalizable.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478470/is-the-zero-matrix-the-only-symmetric-nilpotent-matrix-with-real-values